# Relation with django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a question, I have 2 tables in my project (Customer, Machine) and I want to display the name of the customer in the MACHINE table. I have the relationship but I have not been able to create the Join. Could you help me validating this topic

Comment: `I have the relationship`: I don't see it anywhere in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You might have this kind of models:

```py
# models.py
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Machine(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can access name of the customer through the machine this way:

```py
c = Customer(name="ABC")
m = Machine(customer=c)
c.save()
m.save()

machine_list = Machine.objects.all()
for machine in machine_list:
     print(machine.customer.name)

>>>
ABC
```

Would be very helpful if you show your models